# Full program in Clojure

Tags: discussion, rules

[This challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/59347/shortest-infinite-loop-producing-no-output/101700#101700) requires us to create a "full program" that produces an infinite loop, and never outputs.

The problem is, I'm not sure what's considered a full program in Clojure.

If I were writing non-golfing code, my project would start out as:

```
(ns package1.package2)

(defn -main [& args])
```

At the bare minimum. I know the `ns` macro is pretty much a requirement for any real code, but is it required for a "full program"?

And what about `-main`? Technically, the main function doesn't even need to be called `-main`; that's just the default. I could name it anything as long as I adjusted the `project.clj` accordingly. I don't think an anonymous function would be passable though since it couldn't be called. Does that mean the only requirement is that it contains a named function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Disclaimer: I know *nothing* about Clojure.</sub>

A *full* program is anything that can be compiled/interpreted on its own, usually from a standalone file, using any pre-existing compiler/interpreter.

For example, a simple hello world program that works on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/QPQ9F6) is

```
(print "Hello, World!")
```

Everything else would be overkill.

Note that if you *do* require the *ns* macro  or a *project.clj* file for any specific task requiring a full program, you would have to include these in your byte count.

Comment: If you paste your Hello World in a otherwise empty file, it will run fine. The namespace macro would only be required if I were including multiple files, in retrospect. Thanks.